# ASP Page naming and Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I have quite the odd scenario I have not run into before.

I simply have a hyper link, with the url hard coded to www.mywebsite.com/StoreLoc.aspx

My application has two pages that we are concerned about.

1. Store.aspx
2. StoreLoc.aspx

Even though the hyperlink is hardcoded to go to StoreLoc.aspx, **SOMETIMES** ( once out of tenish ) the hyperlink will direct to Store.aspx instead.

I am not the first person to work on this application, so the aspx files very well may have been renamed.  Could this cause this issue?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: If this error is reproduce-able; check the headers sent/received by the browser.  There may be a redirect kicking in.

Comment: It might be a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something in the OnSesssionStart function of the Global.asax file the does a Response.Redirect to Store.aspx.

You session might be getting killed after x minutes of inactivity. This would cause the session to get started again and then get redirected to the start page.

You may want to search for Respose.redirect or Server.Transfer in your visual studio solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oops thought I had accepted this answer.  This was indeed my issue good sir, thank you.